# Cannot call objects c++

Tags: c++, class, object, header

I'm new to c++ and stack overflow so excuse me if I don't completely understand what your saying, my goal is to convert my tic tac toe code from using functions into classes and objects using header files.

After creating an object that returns a string to be used in the outcome by int main, I declare it in main.cpp and when trying to call it in an if statement(`if (rps(p1, p2) == "tie")`) I get the "identifier is undefined" error. I have called these objects before in guided tutorials and looking back at the projects and implementing this into it, it works. I think it has something to do with the scope of the program but I have tried moving it around and other things and just need some help(my code is provided below).

This is my creation of the object in main.cpp

```
std::string Game::rps(std::string p1, std::string p2)
{
    std::string tie = "tie";
    std::string p1w = "p1w";
    std::string p2w = "p2w";
    //tie
    if (p1 == p2) {
        return tie;
    }
    //rock vs sci p1
    if (p1 == "rock" && p2 == "scissor") {
        return p1w;
    }
    //rock vs sci p2
    if (p2 == "rock" && p1 == "scissor") {
        return p2w;
    }
    //paper vs rock p1
    if (p1 == "paper" && p2 == "rock") {
        return p1w;
    }
    //paper vs rock p2
    if (p2 == "paper" && p1 == "rock") {
        return p2w;
    }
    //sci vs paper p1
    if (p1 == "scissor" && p2 == "paper") {
        return p1w;
    }
    //sci vs paper p2
    if (p2 == "scissor" && p1 == "paper") {
        return p2w;
    }
}
```

Calling the object:

```
if (rps(p1, p2) == "tie") {
    cout << "Same Move, Try Again!" << "\n" << "\n";
}
```

Header File:

```
#pragma once
#include <string>

class Game
{
public:

private:
    std::string rps(std::string p1, std::string p2);
};
```

Comment: `if (rps(p1, p2) == "tie"))` is only valid if done in a non-static member function of `Game`.   Otherwise it needs to be written as `if (some_object.rps(p1, p2) == "tie"))` or as `if (some_pointer->rps(p1, p2) == "tie"))`  where `some_object` is (a reference to) an object of type `Game`, or `some_pointer` is a pointer that points at such an object.  Since `rps()` is private, the calling code needs to be declared as a `friend`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the member function `rps` will be inaccessible, if you want it to be called by class users (i.e. in the `main`, not internally by class instances), you need to put it in `public`.

```
class Game {
public:
    std::string rps(std::string p1, std::string p2);
};
```

Then you'll need to create an instance of the `Game` in `main`. As in

```
int main () {
    Game g;
    std::string p1, p2;
    // Assume we assigned some values to p1 and p2
    if (g.rps(p1, p2) == "tie") {
        cout << "Same Move, Try Again!" << "\n" << "\n";
    }
}
```

Note, we call the public member function on created instance of the Game class, the object `g`. So, we first need to instantiate the `Game` class, since the class itself is only a recipe for creation of "tangible" objects.

Comment: @Nurved, you're welcome! Don't forget to accept the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

1. You must put function rps into **public** in order to use it in **main**
2. You must **declare** your **instance of class member** in main [Ex: Game player1 (Game is a name of your declared class)]